# how to do batch processing on minimization of non-linear function in matlab

Tags: matlab, minimization

I have a 3D image `V`. For each pixel `v` in this 3D image, I need to minimize a function

```
(Y1 - F1(x1, x2))^2 + (Y2 - F2(x1, x2))^2
```

`Y1` and `Y2` are two observations. `F1` and `F2` are non-linear functions, derivable, but in a complicated form. `x1` and `x2` are two unknowns.

I know how to solve this problem **pixel by pixel** using `lsqnonlin` or `lsqcurvefit` in matlab. But it was so slow. Anyone can tell me how to solve this problem in the whole image? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are Y1 and Y2 in terms of the pixel data? RGB values?

Comment: It seems you know how F1 and F2 behave. Why not calculate them for a lot of points, look at the results and check whether you can find the optimum? If you are sure they are in a certain area you can repeat the process with a lot of points in that area.

Comment: Not RGB. Signal intensities.

Comment: Yes, I know F1 and F2. The forms are fixed for all pixels. But what do you mean "calculate them for a lot of points"? how?

Comment: Following up on what @DennisJaheruddin commented, perhaps you can discretize the problem and set up a look up table in advance.

Comment: As the functions `F1` and `F2` always require the same inputs `(x1, x2)` (and not combinations), a lookup table will only help if you evaluate overlapping regions. Hence I think you cannot gain anything by doing this in advance, but it may help to keep track of results as you go.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you should try [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html). It is designed for this kind problem.

If fminsearch cannot help you, but you know something about how they behave, you can try using a manual quantitative approach (just calculating it at a lot of points and see if it behaves well).

If your functions can handle vectorized inputs, it can be done like this:

```
vec1 = 0:0.1:10; %Assume you expect it somewhere between 0 and 10
vec2 = 0:0.1:10;
[x1, x2] = ndgrid(vec1, vec2); 
result = (Y1 - F1(x1, x2))^2 + (Y2 - F2(x1, x2))^2
```

If this does not work, you can do this:

```
horzcount = 0;
for x1 = vec1
   horzcount = horzcount +1;
   vertcount = 0;
   for x2 = vec2
      vertcount = vertcount + 1;
      result(horzcount, vertcount) = (Y1 - F1(x1, x2))^2 + (Y2 - F2(x1, x2))^2;
   end
end
```

Afterwards look at the result (use `surf` on an area or `plot` on a row or column) and determine whet you are satisfied to have found the region that contains the optimum.
Then zoom in on that region by adjusting vec1 and vec2 accordingly untill you have achieved sufficient precision.

Comment: So why not perform a grid search with precalculated F1 and F2?

Comment: @TryHard If the function was like `F1(x1,x2) + F2(x3,x4)`, or `F1(x1,x2)+ F1(x1,x2)`, I would recommend precalculating. But as it now is like `F1(x1,x2)+ F2(x1,x2)` I don't see how precalculations could be used to improve efficiency. (Except when you evaluate overlapping areas, but in that case I would store the results rather than function values)

Comment: Ok, I don't get it: you need to store *twice* as many function values with F1 *and* F2, but otherwise it should work just as well... maybe I should post as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @DennisJaheruddin's answer, there is some point at which a grid search is less computationally expensive than minimization of an objective function using simplex, and occurs even for small images if evaluating functions `F1,F2` is much more costly than performing the arithmetic to compute the objective function (for `F1, F2` precalculated)

I would first get an idea of the solution range and required precision of the solution values, then compute `vec1` and `vec2` as proposed by @DennisJaheruddin, as vectors spanning the range, and precompute `F1(x1, x2)`  and `F2(x1, x2)`

Then for each point find

```
Imin = min((Y1 - F1).^2 + (Y2 - F2).^2)
```

Looks like this can be vectorized. The solutions `Imin` index into the original grid so you can figure out X1min and X2min at each pixel.